# Adding Additional Arguments to \title{} command in moderncv classic format

Tags: positioning, titles, moderncv

I want to add an extra argument to the \title{} command in moderncv so that I can bring the "last updated"...... to the cross mark and the title should be at the top right corner like I have shown. I am using the classic format. I have tried a lot but in vain. Any help in this regard is appreciated. Here is the sample code and its output. This is the code of the preamble of my document.

---

### CODE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{red} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\usepackage{ leftidx}
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{255,127,0}

\newcommand*{\skypesymbol} {%
  \protect\raisebox{-0.085em}{%
\protect\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.08em,x=0.08em,xscale=0.022,yscale=-0.022, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\protect\path[fill=orange,even odd rule] (487.6550,288.9690) .. controls (489.0610,278.5690) and
  (489.8700,267.9960) .. (489.8700,257.2330) .. controls (489.8700,128.0770) and
  (384.5990,23.3610) .. (254.7670,23.3610) .. controls (241.8630,23.3610) and
  (229.2120,24.4210) .. (216.9010,26.4410) .. controls (194.8280,12.0570) and
  (168.5590,3.6740) .. (140.2880,3.6740) .. controls (62.7660,3.6740) and
  (0.0000,66.4820) .. (0.0000,143.9800) .. controls (0.0000,172.1780) and
  (8.2990,198.3740) .. (22.5900,220.3690) .. controls (20.6650,232.3860) and
  (19.6810,244.6920) .. (19.6810,257.2290) .. controls (19.6810,386.4050) and
  (124.8980,491.1100) .. (254.7660,491.1100) .. controls (269.4230,491.1100) and
  (283.6930,489.6840) .. (297.5620,487.1780) .. controls (319.1120,500.5470) and
  (344.4960,508.3260) .. (371.7080,508.3260) .. controls (449.2100,508.3260) and
  (512.0010,445.5020) .. (512.0010,368.0120) .. controls (511.9980,338.7190) and
  (503.0410,311.4840) .. (487.6550,288.9690) -- cycle(276.7400,429.5960) ..
  controls (202.0340,433.4870) and (167.0750,416.9590) .. (135.0500,386.9050) ..
  controls (99.2850,353.3370) and (113.6520,315.0500) .. (142.7900,313.1040) ..
  controls (171.9120,311.1590) and (189.3980,346.1160) .. (204.9410,355.8400) ..
  controls (220.4650,365.5280) and (279.5340,387.6000) .. (310.7350,351.9320) ..
  controls (344.7100,313.1040) and (288.1410,293.0120) .. (246.6760,286.9300) ..
  controls (187.4730,278.1640) and (112.7260,246.1370) .. (118.5410,183.0230) ..
  controls (124.3580,119.9490) and (172.1230,87.6090) .. (222.3910,83.0470) ..
  controls (286.4680,77.2300) and (328.1820,92.7540) .. (361.1760,120.9070) ..
  controls (399.3270,153.4360) and (378.6840,189.8010) .. (354.3770,192.7270) ..
  controls (330.1660,195.6360) and (302.9730,139.2230) .. (249.5860,138.3750) ..
  controls (194.5590,137.5110) and (157.3690,195.6360) .. (225.3000,212.1590) ..
  controls (293.2660,228.6640) and (366.0500,235.4450) .. (392.2610,297.5760) ..
  controls (418.4900,359.7130) and (351.5070,425.7010) .. (276.7400,429.5960) --
  cycle;
\protect\end{tikzpicture}}%
  ~}

\makeatletter
% defines one's email (optional)
% usage: \email{<email adress>}
\newcommand*{\skype}[1]{\def\@skype{#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
% recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
\recomputecvlengths%
% optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
\def\phonesdetails{}%
\collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
\protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\def\socialsdetails{}%
\collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
\protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
\addressfont\color{orange}%

\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}%
\makenewline
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
  \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}{}{\makenewline{\skypesymbol\@skype}}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
  \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
\end{tabular}}%

% optional photo (pre-rendering)
\newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
 {
    \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}% Damit Länge bekannt bei Name
    \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{0pt}%
  }%
  {%
   \setlength\fboxrule{\@photoframewidth}%
   \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
     \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
   {\color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}
    \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}%
    \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  }%
% end define optional picture
% optional title
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\null\hfill\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[1.5em]%
% optional detailed information (rendering)
{\raggedright\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname}{\color{color2}\@familyname}}\\[1em]
\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of
\hfill\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
\\[-.35em]%
{\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
}%
\pagestyle{plain}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\address}{mG{}G{}G{}}{%
  \def\@addressapartment{#1}\def\@addressstreetonly{#2}\def\@addresscity{#3}\def\@addresscountry{#4}%
  \def\@addressstreet{%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressapartment}}{}{\@addressapartment}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreetonly}}{}{\makenewline\@addressstreetonly}%
  }}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\rfoot{\textit{\small{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}}
\graphicspath{ {photo/} }
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\firstname{} % Your first name
\familyname{Abinash \textcolor{black}{Kar}}% Your last name. All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Curriculum Vitae\newline{}
\scriptsize{\textnormal{Last Updated}\textnormal{ :} \textbf{January, 2015}}
}
\mobile{\color{color2}+91-7205044899}
\skype{\color{color2}kar.abinash93}
\email{kar.abinash@outlook.com}
\address{\textifsymbol{18} \color{color2}Room No.\ C-205, M.S Swaminathan Hall of Residence,}{\ \ \ \color{color2}NIT Campus, NIT Rourkela, Rourkela -- 769008,}{\ \ \ \color{color2}District -- Sundergarh, State -- Odisha, India.}
\extrainfo{%
  \color{color2}\\ \color{color2}Date of Birth -- $15$\textsuperscript{th} July, 1993 \\
  \color{color2}Gender -- Male\\
  \color{color2}Nationality -- Indian
}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=cyan}
}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 5):

Here it is

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{red} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\usepackage{ leftidx}
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{255,127,0}

\newcommand*{\skypesymbol} {%
  \protect\raisebox{-0.085em}{%
\protect\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.08em,x=0.08em,xscale=0.022,yscale=-0.022, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\protect\path[fill=orange,even odd rule] (487.6550,288.9690) .. controls (489.0610,278.5690) and
  (489.8700,267.9960) .. (489.8700,257.2330) .. controls (489.8700,128.0770) and
  (384.5990,23.3610) .. (254.7670,23.3610) .. controls (241.8630,23.3610) and
  (229.2120,24.4210) .. (216.9010,26.4410) .. controls (194.8280,12.0570) and
  (168.5590,3.6740) .. (140.2880,3.6740) .. controls (62.7660,3.6740) and
  (0.0000,66.4820) .. (0.0000,143.9800) .. controls (0.0000,172.1780) and
  (8.2990,198.3740) .. (22.5900,220.3690) .. controls (20.6650,232.3860) and
  (19.6810,244.6920) .. (19.6810,257.2290) .. controls (19.6810,386.4050) and
  (124.8980,491.1100) .. (254.7660,491.1100) .. controls (269.4230,491.1100) and
  (283.6930,489.6840) .. (297.5620,487.1780) .. controls (319.1120,500.5470) and
  (344.4960,508.3260) .. (371.7080,508.3260) .. controls (449.2100,508.3260) and
  (512.0010,445.5020) .. (512.0010,368.0120) .. controls (511.9980,338.7190) and
  (503.0410,311.4840) .. (487.6550,288.9690) -- cycle(276.7400,429.5960) ..
  controls (202.0340,433.4870) and (167.0750,416.9590) .. (135.0500,386.9050) ..
  controls (99.2850,353.3370) and (113.6520,315.0500) .. (142.7900,313.1040) ..
  controls (171.9120,311.1590) and (189.3980,346.1160) .. (204.9410,355.8400) ..
  controls (220.4650,365.5280) and (279.5340,387.6000) .. (310.7350,351.9320) ..
  controls (344.7100,313.1040) and (288.1410,293.0120) .. (246.6760,286.9300) ..
  controls (187.4730,278.1640) and (112.7260,246.1370) .. (118.5410,183.0230) ..
  controls (124.3580,119.9490) and (172.1230,87.6090) .. (222.3910,83.0470) ..
  controls (286.4680,77.2300) and (328.1820,92.7540) .. (361.1760,120.9070) ..
  controls (399.3270,153.4360) and (378.6840,189.8010) .. (354.3770,192.7270) ..
  controls (330.1660,195.6360) and (302.9730,139.2230) .. (249.5860,138.3750) ..
  controls (194.5590,137.5110) and (157.3690,195.6360) .. (225.3000,212.1590) ..
  controls (293.2660,228.6640) and (366.0500,235.4450) .. (392.2610,297.5760) ..
  controls (418.4900,359.7130) and (351.5070,425.7010) .. (276.7400,429.5960) --
  cycle;
\protect\end{tikzpicture}}%
  ~}

\makeatletter
% defines one's email (optional)
% usage: \email{<email adress>}
\newcommand*{\skype}[1]{\def\@skype{#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
% recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
\recomputecvlengths%
% optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
\def\phonesdetails{}%
\collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
\protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\def\socialsdetails{}%
\collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
\protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
\addressfont\color{orange}%

\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}%
\makenewline
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
  \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}{}{\makenewline{\skypesymbol\@skype}}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
  \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
\end{tabular}}%

% optional photo (pre-rendering)
\newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
 {
    \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}% Damit Länge bekannt bei Name
    \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{0pt}%
  }%
  {%
   \setlength\fboxrule{\@photoframewidth}%
   \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
     \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
   {\color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}
    \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}%
    \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  }%
% end define optional picture
% optional title
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\raggedleft\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[1.5em]%
% optional detailed information (rendering)
\raggedright\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname}{\color{color2}\@familyname}\\[.5em]
\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of
\hfill\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
\\[-.35em]%
{\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
}%
\pagestyle{plain}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\address}{mG{}G{}G{}}{%
  \def\@addressapartment{#1}\def\@addressstreetonly{#2}\def\@addresscity{#3}\def\@addresscountry{#4}%
  \def\@addressstreet{%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressapartment}}{}{\@addressapartment}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreetonly}}{}{\makenewline\@addressstreetonly}%
  }}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\rfoot{\textit{\small{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}}
\graphicspath{ {photo/} }
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\firstname{} % Your first name
\familyname{Abinash \textcolor{black}{Kar}}% Your last name. All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Curriculum Vitae\\
\scriptsize{\textnormal{Last Updated}\textnormal{ :} \textbf{January, 2015}}
}
\mobile{\color{color2}+91-7205044899}
\skype{\color{color2}kar.abinash93}
\email{kar.abinash@outlook.com}
\address{\textifsymbol{18} \color{color2}Room No.\ C-205, M.S Swaminathan Hall of Residence,}{\ \ \ \color{color2}NIT Campus, NIT Rourkela, Rourkela -- 769008,}{\ \ \ \color{color2}District -- Sundergarh, State -- Odisha, India.}
\extrainfo{%
  \color{color2}\\ \color{color2}Date of Birth -- $15$\textsuperscript{th} July, 1993 \\
  \color{color2}Gender -- Male\\
  \color{color2}Nationality -- Indian
}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=cyan}
}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

I've changed

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\null\hfill\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[1.5em]%
% optional detailed information (rendering)
{\raggedright\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname}{\color{color2}\@familyname}}\\[1em]
```

to

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\raggedleft\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[1.5em]%
% optional detailed information (rendering)
\raggedright\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname}{\color{color2}\@familyname}\\[.5em]
```

and

```
\title{Curriculum Vitae\newline{}
\scriptsize{\textnormal{Last Updated}\textnormal{ :} \textbf{January, 2015}}
}
```

to

```
\title{Curriculum Vitae\\
\scriptsize{\textnormal{Last Updated}\textnormal{ :} \textbf{January, 2015}}}
```